# Problema ao executar jar compactado manualmente

Tags: java

Eu estava estudando como compilar java direto pelo javac e tudo mais. Depois juntei todos os arquivos em um zip e renomeei para .jar .
Não funcionou primeiramente devido a falta do Manifest - não 'achava a classe principal'

Mas mesmo se eu entrasse diretamente usando -cp o erro persiste.

Quando adicionei o manifest surgio a mensagen : **Invalid or corrupted jarfile**

Tive uma hipótese de que um jar não seria exatamente um zip, mas mesmo eu extraindo um jar(funcional) e compactando novamente, nada de errado acontece.
Qual erro cometi então?

Comment: Qual a dúvida? Aparentemente você mesmo se esclareceu no texto.

Comment: Editei, acho que eu sou muito ruim em deixar as coisas claras

Comment: Vc compacto os arquivos que pertencem ao jar para zip, e alterou a extensão para jar? Se foi isso acho que não vai executar mesmo, não tenho certeza se roda normal.

Comment: Existe uma ferramenta que faz parte do SDK que serve pra isso. Dê uma olhada em https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html . Se você não conseguir por causa do inglês, avise que eu faço uma resposta completa em português assim que eu puder testar.

Answer (score 0):

Para gerar um .jar você não pode apenas compactá-lo. Você deve compilar o seu código-fonte (.java) para que seja gerado um bytecode (.class). O JVM interpreta apenas esse tipo de arquivo.

Segue o link de um material sobre esse assunto => http://www.devmedia.com.br/etapas-do-desenvolvimento-e-execucao-de-uma-aplicacao-java/25099

O que você poderia fazer é usar o javac para gerar os arquivos .class (bytecodes) e depois compactá-los usando o Winrar. Junto com os arquivos compactados, você deverá incluir o manifest com o caminho da classe principal(a clase que possui o método public static void mamin(String args))